# Select random value from row in a TF.record array, with limits on what the value can be?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say that I have a Tf.record file, and each row in the tf.records contain ints that are 0 or positive, and then padded with -1 so that all the rows are even size. So something like

```
0 3 43 223 23 -1 -1 -1
4 12 3  11  435 2 4 -1
9 3 11 32  34 322 9 7
. 
. 
.
```

How do I randomly select 3 numbers from each of the rows ?

The numbers will act like indexes to look up values in an embedding matrix, and then those embeddings will be averaged (basically word2vec CBOW model).

More specifically, how do I avoid selecting the padding values of '-1'. -1 is just what I used to pad my rows so that each row will be the same size in order to use tf.record.(If there is a way to use varying length rows in tfrecords, let me know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like [tf.VarLenFeature()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/VarLenFeature), more specifically, you do not necessarily have to pad your rows prior to creating the tfrecord file. You can create the tf_example,

```
from tensorflow.train import BytesList, Feature, Features, Example, Int64List

tf_example = Example(
    features=Features(
        feature={
            "my_feature": Feature(
                int64_list=Int64List(value=[0,3,43,223,23])
            )
        })
    )
)

with TFRecordWriter(tfrecord_file_path) as tf_writer:
    tf_writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
```

Do this for all of your rows, that can vary in length.

You'll parse the tf_examples with something like,

```
def parse_tf_example(example):
    feature_spec = {
        "my_feature": tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64)
    }
    return tf.parse_example([example], features=feature_spec)
```

Now, this will return your features as [tf.SparseTensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor)s, if you don't want to deal with that at this stage, and carry on using tensor ops as you would normally, you can simply use [tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse_tensor_to_dense) and carry on as you normally would with tensors.

The returned dense tensors will be of varying lengths, so you shouldn't have to worry about selecting '-1's, there won't be any. *Unless you convert the sparse tensors to dense in batches*, in that case the batches will be padded to the length of the longest tensor in the batch, and the padding value can be set by the `default_value` parameter.

That is in so far as your question about using varying length rows in tfrecords and getting back varying length tensors.

With regards to the lookup op, I haven't used it myself, but I think [tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/embedding_lookup_sparse) might help you out here, it offers the ability to lookup the embeddings from the sparse tensor, forgoing the need to convert it to a dense tensor first, and also has a `combiner` parameter to specify a reduction op on those embeddings, which in your case would be 'mean'.

I hope this helps in some way, good luck.

Comment: Thanks! Though I'm getting an error when I try to convert the sparse tensor to a dense one. I set  `tfrecord_file_path = 'testTFrecord' ` and executed the first code block in your ansewr. Then I executed the second code block to define the function, then I executed `duh = parse_tf_example('testTFrecord')` . Then I executed `rows = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(duh)` but then I get `TypeError: Input must be a SparseTensor.` error

Comment: If you used the code as I posted it above the sparse tensor will be `duh["my_feature"]`. I know this stuff is a little tricky sometimes, minute differences make annoying differences in the output that are hard to look into. If it still gives you trouble, try firing up an iPython Notebook with `tf.enable_eager_execution()`, that will allow you to print out the contents of your variables, and make it easier to spot where your SparseTensor is.

Comment: Also note, the `parse_tf_example(example)` function I provided is something I would normally map over a [tf.data.TFRecordDataset](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset), to get the actual data, not simply passing the path to the tfrecord file. You can find a better example of what I mean [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_tfrecord_data), apologies if that wasn't clear in my answer.