# Converting a Numpy file to TFRecord where each row contains a number, and a variable length list

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

This is a follow up to these two SO questions

[Select random value from row in a TF.record array, with limits on what the value can be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53073085/select-random-value-from-row-in-a-tf-record-array-with-limits-on-what-the-value)

[Numpy array to TFrecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416742/numpy-array-to-tfrecord)

The first one mentioned that tfrecords can handle variable length data using `tf.VarLenFeature()`

I am still having trouble figuring how how to convert my number array to tfrecord file though. Here's what the first 10 rows looks like

```
print(my_data[0:15])

[[1446549
  list([491827, 30085, 1417541, 799563, 879302, 1997973, 1373049, 1460602, 2240973, 1172992, 1186011, 147536, 1958456, 3095889, 319954, 2191582, 1113354, 302626, 1985611, 1186704, 2231212, 2642148, 386962, 3072993, 1131255, 15085, 2714264, 1363205])]
 [406529 list([900479, 660976, 1270383, 1287181])]
 [1350274
  list([207721, 676951, 1311781, 2712019, 1719660, 2969693, 37187, 2284531, 1253304, 1274866, 2815382, 1513583, 1339084, 1624616, 2967307, 1702118, 585261, 426595, 1444507, 1982792])]
 [1163243
  list([324383, 81509, 322474, 406941, 768416, 109067, 173425, 1478467, 573723, 1009159, 313463, 313924, 627680, 1072293, 1025620, 2325337, 2457705, 1505115, 2812547, 922812, 2152425, 2524196, 182325, 2912690, 1388620, 1484514, 1481728, 2616639, 2180765, 1544586, 1987272, 1557441, 453182, 892217, 1462085, 1892770, 1646735, 2521186, 2814552, 2983691, 3037096, 832554, 2807250, 2253333, 2595688, 2650475, 2525317, 2716592, 2573244, 2666514, 256757, 1135836, 1856208, 2605537, 1851963, 2381938, 1716883, 773842, 1877852, 2504806, 2208699, 1076111, 3058991, 3024546, 2010887, 2630915])]
 [2491621 list([877803, 546802, 2855232, 2950610, 1378514, 285536])]
 [2465968
  list([626040, 1151291, 560715, 1153787, 893941, 3094902, 1239392, 2081948, 1677321, 1193880, 2326117, 2805797, 1715983, 1213177, 1476995, 2620772, 1242804, 2942330, 588938, 2338375, 2805378, 169015, 1766962, 562485, 1210404, 772334, 415148, 1293624, 527245, 587088, 665484, 449673, 315509])]
 [886255
  list([694445, 796232, 1151072, 2312348, 1773175, 1898319, 1696093, 91310, 719379, 2080422, 1352695, 2364846, 845154, 2476191, 537059, 1216854, 1529449, 284855, 1215830, 3041789, 1625939])]
 [451113
  list([2805707, 2727647, 742706, 1727139, 2585759, 822759, 1099617])]
 [1529600
  list([1755946, 2110553, 1056110, 426876, 2448684, 396996, 1498300, 756831, 2181288, 1159493])]
 [596550 list([1610895, 2579387, 3081786, 2000733, 2142308])]
 [1631548
  list([1576412, 849908, 2705650, 2291675, 751733, 1911747, 1496204])]
 [3001784 list([327334, 1197547, 2515733])]
 [308747
  list([8344, 80684, 996504, 2250076, 1905654, 863587, 2235560, 2676079, 1826, 685487, 1481871, 588465, 1126662, 2458841, 2481927])]
 [731288 list([2793620, 1115724, 1406934])]
 [1523219
  list([12825, 1128776, 1761080, 1486798, 2689369, 1040645, 3012606])]]
```

Might be a little tricky to read but here's an instance of a smaller row

`[406529 list([900479, 660976, 1270383, 1287181])]`

Each now contains a number, and a list of numbers, and that list varies in length.

I am having trouble figuring out how exactly I can convert this to a tfrecord file. Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to add numbers feature and list feature respectively here.

```
import tensorflow as tf

writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter('test.tfrecords')
for index in range(my_data.shape[0]):
    example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'num_value':tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[my_data[index][0]])),
        'list_value':tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=my_data[index][1]))
    }))
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())
writer.close()

#read data from tfrecords
record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator('test.tfrecords')
for _ in range(2):
    seralized_img_example = next(record_iterator)
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(seralized_img_example)
    num_value = example.features.feature['num_value'].int64_list.value[0]
    list_value = example.features.feature['list_value'].int64_list.value
    print(num_value,list_value)

#print
1446549 [491827, 30085, 1417541, 799563, 879302, 1997973, 1373049, 1460602, 2240973, 1172992, 1186011, 147536, 1958456, 3095889, 319954, 2191582, 1113354, 302626, 1985611, 1186704, 2231212, 2642148, 386962, 3072993, 1131255, 15085, 2714264, 1363205]
406529 [900479, 660976, 1270383, 1287181]
```